# What does a Syntax bounceback actually mean?

Tags: civimail

If we have an email bounce back due to "syntax", what does that actually mean?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the report under Reports - Mail Reports - Bounce Report to include the bounce reason column and it will give more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the search patterns that will [classify a bounce as syntax here.](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/sql/civicrm_data/civicrm_mailing_bounce_type/Syntax.sqldata.php)